# converter valor de imagem em BLOB para imagem.jpg novamente

Tags: php, sql, banco-de-dados

Preciso fazer com que o código abaixo não mostre o valor blob da imagem q foi salva no banco, mas mostre ela em figura.jpg pra listar na tela. como posso converter dentro desse código mesmo?

```
<?php

require_once "conexao.class.php";

try
 {
   $conecta = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=informacoes;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
   $conecta->exec("set names utf8"); //permite caracteres latinos.

   $consultaSQL = "SELECT imagem FROM escolhida1 WHERE 1";
   $exComando = $conecta->prepare($consultaSQL); //testar o comando
   $exComando->execute(array());
   foreach($exComando as $resultado)
   {
     $png = "png";
     $conteudo = $resultado['imagem'];
     header("Content-Type: $png");
     echo $conteudo;
   } 
  }catch(PDOException $erro)
   {
     echo("Errrooooo! foi esse: " . $erro->getMessage());
   }
?>
```

Comment: perdão pessoal, não é jpg, na pergunta, é PNG mesmo

Answer (score 0):

Content-Type pra imagens PNG é "image/png", e não "png". [MIME types](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Basico_sobre_HTTP/MIME_types)

Se tu tem certeza que o BLOB que está armazenado no banco de dados é uma imagem, tu pode "simplesmente" escrever este BLOB para um arquivo. O BLOB é a imagem binária.

Se tu quiser exibir em uma página HTML, então ou tu salva em um arquivo e usa o caminho do arquivo como atributo **src** da tag , ou usa o data do HTML5:

```
<img src="data:Content-Type: image/<?php echo $png; ?>;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($conteudo); ?>" />
```

---

Eu faria alguns testes antes de tentar renderizar uma imagem desta forma pra ter certeza de que é uma imagem de fato e de que não tem nenhum vírus no BLOB da imagem.